# Os buscadores interpretam os elementos antes ou depois de renderizados pelo Javascript?

Tags: javascript, seo

Por exemplo, em um `ng-repeat`do Angular ou em simples `append` do Jquery, os buscadores irão ler todos os elementos criados dinamicamente, já que se trata de um *replace* client-side?

No trecho abaixo, tomando o exemplo do Jquery, eu tenho uma `div.blockquote` que será substituída por uma tag real `<blockquote>` assim como seu conteúdo que, como está em uma formatação predefinida, será divido em várias tags para que se preserve a semântica. Os buscadores irão levar em consideração essa nova tag e suas "filhas"?

```js
(function blockquote(){
 $('.blockquote').each(function(i){
   var self = $(this);
    var phrase = self.html().split(/---/)[0].replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    var footer = self.html().split(/---/)[1];
    var autor  = footer.split('#')[0];
    var autorHref = footer.split('#')[1];
    var blockquote = $('<blockquote></blockquote>');
    var text = $('<p></p>');
    var line = $('<hr>');
    var footer = $('<footer></footer>');
    var cite = $('<cite></cite>');
    blockquote.insertAfter(self);
    text.appendTo(blockquote).html(phrase);
    line.appendTo(blockquote);
    footer.appendTo(blockquote).html(' - ');
    cite.appendTo(footer).html('<a href="'+autorHref+'" target="_blank">'+autor+'</a>');
    blockquote.find('br:last, br:first').remove();
    blockquote.children('p').prepend('<br>');
    self.remove();
  })
})();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
blockquote {
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 10px solid #3c948b;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
blockquote p {
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
blockquote:before {
  content: '"';
  font-size: 38pt;
  font-family: 'Impact', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #3c948b;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  position: absolute;
}
blockquote p:after {
  content: '"';
}
blockquote hr {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: #3c948b;
  height: 1px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -2px;
  border: 0;
}
blockquote footer {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
blockquote footer cite a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3c948b;
}
blockquote footer cite a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #3c948b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<div class="blockquote">
  A primeira condição para modificar a realidade consiste em conhecê-la. --- Eduardo Galeano # https://www.google.com/
</div>
```

Comment: Não vou responder agora devido a falta de tempo pra formular uma resposta descente, mas vou lhe adiantar que sim, o Google indexa páginas geradas por javascript, no entanto é necessário usar a "History API" do javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API - como por exemplo `pushState`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, vou dar uma boa olhada nessa API, enquanto aguardo sua resposta. Desde já obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, pelo menos o Crawler do Google se comporta muito bem, até mesmo em casos perculiares, como à seguinte analise tenta mostrar: [We Tested How Googlebot Crawls Javascript And Here’s What We Learned](http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157)

Comment: @TobyMosque sim, exato o google é o melhor, o bing/yahoo (mesma engine) é +ou-, mas também funciona. Ótimo link.

Comment: @TobyMosque, realmente, ótimo link. Obrigado!

Comment: Em geral, os motores de busca vai ver que não é JavaScript e pode supor que o DOM vai mudar. meta tags apropriadas são importantes também.